# Save/print custom range to pdf-file

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a pdf-file where every odd page is in English, and every even page is in French. I'm only interested in the English pages, and therefore want to create a new pdf where all the French pages are removed. The twist is: In the start I want only the pages 1 and 4 That is, I want the pages:

```
1,4,7,9,11,13,15 ... 151
```

This means I can't use the `Print only odd pages`, as this would print pages 3 and 5, instead of 4. I could do this in any programming language to get this list, but when I paste this list I only get to 51 (maximum number of custom page numbers).

I'm using CutePDF writer now (but I can switch to some other free software if that's necessary). I don't have Adobe Acrobat. Is what I want possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, here's my work-around:

1. Print pages 1, 4 to pdf using custom range
2. Print pages 7 - 151 to pdf, but only print odd pages
3. Merge pdf-files using a pdf-creater.
4. Print the newly created pdf-file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Print your PDF from the Acrobat PDF Reader into a CutePDF printer and chose the exact page number list you prefer from the Pages to print -> Pages, for example 1,4,7,9,11,13,15. This should create a new PDF with your pages. (Use smething else to generate your number list if it's too long, maybe excel !? ).
I don't think the builtin menu can accomodate such specific options for everyone of us, you have to make do with what you have.

Comment: As I stated in the question, the list is too long for the Custom Range field, thus that approach won't help me. I could create two pdfs and merge them, but I don't think that's possible in CutePDF. Probably some other tool is better?